# Pegar váriavel de um form e puxar no outro form

Tags: c#, variáveis

Boa noite,
 estou quebrando a cabeça de como pegar o valor de um formulário e armazenar em uma variável assim podendo acessar esse valor em qualquer outro form.

Tentei já como o public static instanciando porém não obtive exito o valor volta nulo.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: é duplicada...só falta decidir de qual: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+form+valor

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Carlos.

Ainda que esta não seja um boa prática, você pode criar uma classe estática que armazena os valores que vc precisa.

```
public static class RepVariaveis
{
    public static string MeuValor { get; set; }
}
```

Assim, no primeiro form, basta atribuir o valor desajado na classe RepVariaveis.

```
RepVariaveis.MeuValor = "xxxx";
```

Porém, este tipo de pratica não é bom pois em um cenario com uma grande quantidade de forms, pode-se tornar-se complicado gere